# gnuplot - splot inline data and point labels

Tags: gnuplot, label

Hi Im using this data to get a 3d/2d like histogram.

I want to label each histogram column with a 'dx cx' label preferable on top of the column.

With my example the graph is drawing correctly, but there are no labels. if I'm using only the `using 1:2:3:4 with labels offset 1` part, it shows the label with no lines. And it only shows the label to the space character, can I somehow escape the space?

Could anyone help please?

```
reset
unset key
set xrange [0:262.5]
set yrange [0:350]
set zrange [0:5]
set xtics 50
set ytics 50 offset .6,-.3
set ztics 1,1
set grid x y z back
set xyplane 0
set terminal pdf
set output "test.pdf"
splot '-' using 1:2:3 with lines, '' using 1:2:3:4 with labels offset 1
27.8409 350 0   
27.8409 350 0.419595    d0 c3
31.8182 350 0.419595    
31.8182 350 0   
31.8182 350 0   
31.8182 350 0.61032 d0 c4
35.7955 350 0.61032 
35.7955 350 0   
35.7955 350 0   
35.7955 350 0.740013    d0 c5
39.7727 350 0.740013    
39.7727 350 0   
39.7727 350 0   
39.7727 350 0.747642    d0 c6
43.75   350 0.747642    
43.75   350 0   
43.75   350 0   
43.75   350 0.633207    d1 c1
47.7273 350 0.633207    
47.7273 350 0   
47.7273 350 0   
47.7273 350 0.442482    d1 c2
51.7045 350 0.442482    
51.7045 350 0   
e
```

Comment: Your second plot is never done. The inline data is gone after the first part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second plot is never done. The inline data is gone after the first part. You have to feed it twice (same dataset again after the "e") or in gp5 you can use a new form of inline data:

```
$data << EOD
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
EOD
splot $data, $data using 1:2:($2**2)
```

If the data comes in via stdin ("-"), you can use `set table` to plot it to a temporary file or to an inline data set `set table $dat; plot "-"; unset table`.